# Ghost viewcontrollers

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uikit

In my iOS app, when transitioning from viewcontroller 2 to 1 using:

```
let storyBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let newViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Start") as! Start
view?.window?.rootViewController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion:nil)
view?.window?.rootViewController?.present(newViewController, animated: false, completion: nil)
```

The transition works fine, but afterwards when I click a button in viewcontroller 1 which leads me to viewcontroller 3 (which is an SKScene)It works too, but when I use the code above to go back to viewcontroller 1, from 3, it shows (an old version) of viewcontroller 2, and then I have to click on the back button to go to viewcontroller 1.

I've tried dismissing viewcontroller 2 every time it transition away.

All of the viewcontrollers is in the same navigation controller but without the topbar

How do I get back to a previous viewcontroller without a ghost showing up?

Comment: Not sure if I understand the problem correctly, but you could use `setViewControllers(_:animated:)` on your navigationController to replace all the controllers it manages with another hierarchy at one go...

Comment: What do you mean @Alladinian

Comment: Also, an exit segue (or a popToRoot if you just want to go to the first controller) would help you unwind from 3 to 1 omitting controller 2...

Comment: How do I declare/use popToRoot?

Comment: You do not declare it. [It's a method of `UINavigationController`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationcontroller/1621855-poptorootviewcontroller)

Comment: When trying         "UINavigationController.popToRootViewController(animated: true)"
I get "Instance member 'popToRootViewController' cannot be used on type 'UINavigationController'; did you mean to use a value of this type instead?"

Comment: The error you get is because it's an _instance_ method (a method belonging to an instance of) and not a static/class method (a method belonging to a Type). You must call this on your navigationController... I hope that this makes sense...

Comment: I figured it out by using         "self.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: false)"
Thank you

Comment: But in my gamescene file this doesn't work             self.view?.window?.rootViewController?.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: false)

Answer (score 0):

Try removing your view controller from the navigations array.

```
var arrViews = self.navigationController?.viewControllers

    for viewController in arrViews! {

        if viewController is YourViewControllerToRemove{

            if let index = arrViews?.index(of: viewController) {
                arrViews?.remove(at: index)
            }
        }
    }

self.navigationController?.viewControllers = arrViews!
```